# Codeigniter Zip Encoding read_file is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip

I want to make and download archive from my existing files. I tried to following code.

```
$this->zip->read_file('/upload/ut/10_33_statement.xls', true);

$this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```

But this code is not working. But when i use following code it is working.

```
$this->zip->add_data('/upload/ut/10_33_statement.xls', '');

$this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```

I can use this code. But i think it is not best way to do this works. Because i no need add data to file. Please help me. What is the best way to do that?

---

Edit

Suddenly It is works. But now second code is not working. :( What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CodeIgniter zip library is broken, and the framework is no longer being maintained. read_file() doesn't work very well.  Use add_data().

add_data() takes two params:

$this->zip->add_data($fileName, $dataToAddInTheFile);

In practice, this would be:

```
$this->zip->add_data('my_spreadsheet.xls', '/upload/ut/10_33_statement.xls');
$this->zip->download('my_spreadsheet.zip');
```

Comment: I also think cI zip library is broken. Because now it is working. But add_data is not working.

Comment: can i use this for file types like `.docx` if yes please update your answer with example..for file type `docx` else please suggest me any other way out..to create a zip file for `docx`

Answer (score 0):

try this .. it work for me

```
public function downloadall(){

        $createdzipname = 'myzipfilename';

        $this->load->library('zip');
        $this->load->helper('download');
        $cours_id = $this->input->post('todownloadall');
        $files = $this->model_travaux->getByID($cours_id); 

        // create new folder 
        $this->zip->add_dir('zipfolder');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $paths = 'http://localhost/uploads/'.$file->file_name.'.docx';
            // add data own data into the folder created
            $this->zip->add_data('zipfolder/'.$paths,file_get_contents($paths));    
        }
        $this->zip->download($createdzipname.'.zip');
    }
```